# Autodesk Forge Viewer Loading time in android getting delay,Performance slow using Xamarin ,Forge Offline Viewer

Tags: xamarin.android, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

When I am Moving or Zooming Out Model Getting to very Slow and Performance also slow, But **BIM360 Mobile Autodesk Application Working Fine in android Mobile.**

So, What I am looking is while the model or object moving in mobile app disable the loading the model data,properties data what operations are operating i want  disable,only image or degsine need to move

if when user selected particular object i will do the my operation based dbid and other OPeration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview) is already optimizing the interaction performance in various ways. For example, it renders the scene *progressively*, meaning that the geometry is being rendered until a specific "millisecond budget" is exceeded, and at that point the rendering stops, giving time to other things (e.g., interaction), and if the camera hasn't moved, the rendering resumes in the next frame.

So, if you still have performance issues, these may be coming from different places. I would recommend running your Forge Viewer application in environments other than Xamarin, for example, directly in a web browser on a mobile and/or desktop device. If the performance is ok, there might be some issues with the Xamarin environment itself (perhaps the GPU acceleration is disabled or unavailable?).